# Issues with multiple nested if-else in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am having trouble with the code below and I am not sure why it does not work.

| Q16a | Q16c | Q17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NA | 31 |
| 2 | NA | 28 |
| 1 | 26 | NA |
| 1 | 29 | NA |
| 1 | 32 | NA |
| 1 | 25 | NA |
| 1 | 25 | NA |

```
Ech_final_nom_BSA <- Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
  mutate(Moins_23_eleves = ifelse(Q16a==1,
                                  ifelse(!is.na(Q16c),ifelse(Q16c<=22,1,0),
                                          NA),
                                          ifelse(!is.na(Q17),ifelse(Q17<=22,1,0),NA
                                              )))
```

As a result I would like the variable *Moins_23_eleves* to be equal 1 when *Q17* or *Q16c* is below 23 but I don't want NA values to equal 0. The code above works but it still considers NAs as 0.

```
table(Ech_final_nom_BSA$Moins_23_eleves, useNA = "always")
```

| 0 | 1 | NA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1076 | 597 | 0 |

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You've given us your expected output but not your input.  That makes life difficult...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question.

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand your question. If we run your first chunk of code on the data you are providing, we get a column `Moins_23_eleves` containing only zeros (which is logical since no value is less than 23 in the columns `Q16c` and `Q17` and that there is always a value in either of the columns). If the column contains only zeros, it means that it contains no `NA`. So why would you expect anything other than a value of 0 for the NA column of the `dataframe` generated by the `table()` function?

Comment: Hello Yes I understand your point. There are also instances where both Q16c and Q17 are NA. In this case I would like them to remain NAs and not turn into 0s.

Comment: O.K. thanks for the clarification. In this case, please find a possible solution with the library `data.table` (cf. answer below). Cheers.

Comment: Hi @David Potrel, I just noticed that you prefer a solution with the library `dplyr`. So, I added this solution (as an edit) at the bottom of my answer below. I think you were looking for the `case_when()` function from the `dplyr` package. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @David Potrel, Did my answer finally solve your problem? If so, please consider marking this answer as "accepted" and/or "upvoted". If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @lovalery. Sorry for the delay, I was working on another project last week. All set, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @David Potrel. No worries about the delay. I'm glad I could help you and wish you the best in your work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you a solution with the package `data.table`. So please find the reprex below.

**Reprex**

- Your modified data (to get all cases)

```r
m <- "Q16a  Q16c    Q17
2   NA  31
2   NA  28
1   NA  NA
1   29  NA
1   22  NA
1   25  NA
1   25  NA"

Ech_final_nom_BSA <- read.table(text = m, header = TRUE)
```

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

Ech_final_nom_BSA <- setDT(Ech_final_nom_BSA)[, Moins_23_eleves := fcase(Q16a == 1 & Q16c < 23 | Q16a == 1 & Q17 < 23, 1,
                                                                         Q16a == 1 & Q16c >= 23 | Q16a == 1 &Q17 >= 23, 0,
                                                                         default = NA)][]
```

- Output

```r
Ech_final_nom_BSA 
#>    Q16a Q16c Q17 Moins_23_eleves
#> 1:    2   NA  31              NA
#> 2:    2   NA  28              NA
#> 3:    1   NA  NA              NA
#> 4:    1   29  NA               0
#> 5:    1   22  NA               1
#> 6:    1   25  NA               0
#> 7:    1   25  NA               0
```

- Check with `table()`

```r
table(factor(Ech_final_nom_BSA$Moins_23_eleves, levels = 0:1) , useNA = "always")
#> 
#>    0    1 <NA> 
#>    3    1    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**EDIT**

Solution with the `dplyr` library

**Reprex**

- Your modified data (to get all cases)

```r
m <- "Q16a  Q16c    Q17
2   NA  31
2   NA  28
1   NA  NA
1   29  NA
1   22  NA
1   25  NA
1   25  NA"
Ech_final_nom_BSA <- read.table(text = m, header = TRUE)
```

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

Ech_final_nom_BSA <- Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
  mutate(Moins_23_eleves = case_when(Q16a==1 & Q16c <= 22 | Q16a == 1 & Q17 <= 22 ~ 1,
                                     Q16a==1 & Q16c > 22 | Q16a == 1 & Q17 > 22 ~ 0)
         )
```

- Output

```r
Ech_final_nom_BSA 
#>   Q16a Q16c Q17 Moins_23_eleves
#> 1    2   NA  31              NA
#> 2    2   NA  28              NA
#> 3    1   NA  NA              NA
#> 4    1   29  NA               0
#> 5    1   22  NA               1
#> 6    1   25  NA               0
#> 7    1   25  NA               0
```

- Check with `table()`

```r
table(factor(Ech_final_nom_BSA$Moins_23_eleves, levels = 0:1) , useNA = "always")
#> 
#>    0    1 <NA> 
#>    3    1    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>